# Finding a visible button

Tags: c#, button, window

i "stole" the code from 
http://improve.dk/archive/2007/04/07/finding-specific-windows.aspx

but instead of writing the class name , title and handle into the console i want to check if a certain button is visible. and if the button is visible i want to maximize the window.

i changed this part =>

```
    private static bool foundWindow(int handle)    
    {
        bool buttonCheck = false;
        IntPtr hButton = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)handle, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxWnd90u21", null);
        if (hButton != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            buttonCheck = true;
        }

        if (buttonCheck)
        {
            ShowWindowAsync(handle, (int)3); // maximize the window
        }

        return true;
    }
the button class is `AfxWnd90u` and the instance is `21`. I wrote this in autoit before and AfxWnd90u21 is 100 % correct. 

the problem is that i cant find the button with AfxWnd90u21. if i only use 

    IntPtr hButton = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)handle, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxWnd90u", null);

all windows get maximized.

It has to be something with the instance.

i hope you can help me,

thanks
```

**Newest Edit**
        i just tried to find the class name with "GetClassName". I find 190~ classes per handle, but the class that i need is not in there.
        iam really desperate
        I hope someone can help me,
        thanks

```
       private static bool foundWindow(int handle)
            {
                int i = 0;
                IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)handle;

               // System.Windows.Forms.Control control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
                StringBuilder sbClass = new StringBuilder(256);

                while (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    ++i;


                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    ////////////// Compare if the classname exists/////
                    GetClassName((int)hWnd, sbClass, sbClass.Capacity);
                    if (sbClass.ToString().Equals("AfxWnd90u21"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(sbClass.ToString());
                    }
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////


                    ////// trying to find the correct class with findwindowEX//////////
                    IntPtr hButton = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxWnd90u21", null);



                    if (hButton != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("true");
                        ShowWindowAsync(handle, (int)2); // maximize the window
                    }
                    hWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hWnd, null, null);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(""+i);
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
lpszWindow [in, optional]

    Type: LPCTSTR

The window name (the window's title). If this parameter is NULL,
all window names match.
```

Looks like with this API, in order to match an instance, you need to give your instances unique window names. Or, you could search through all children manually cast to a Control, then check the instances yourself.

But if you go that far, it's easier to cast the parent to a Control, and iterate through it's .Controls member. You can use reflection to check the control's type and so on.

To convert a handle to a control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx

Iterate over Control.Controls using whichever loop style you prefer.

Comment: thanks,
i tried to iterate the childrens but it didnt work. could you give me an example of casting a handle to a control and iterate it though their members ?
i just found this @ msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908149.aspx 
sry but iam totally confused

Comment: ok,
but iam still a little bit confused. i got the type conversion     System.Windows.Forms.Control control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);

i checked all member function of control, the only functions that could help is control.contains  but it needs a control as a parameter
how am i supposted to check the classes with a control object?

or can i check the classes with "lpszWindow" that you posted before ?

Comment: @MaikKlein foreach(Control control in Control.Controls) { }